# What is the format of 'date' when for highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I am constructing JSON data structure in python and passing it to Highcharts.StockChart but I can't seem to figure out what format date/timestamp has to be.

Here is how JSON data looks like:

```
  {'chart_data': {'dates': ['07/29/14 23:50', '07/29/14 23:45' ], 
                    'values': [ {'data': [59, 72] } ] 
    }
```

FWIW - I am generating timestamp using this function in python

```
    myData['dates'].append(r.event_time.strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M'))
```

I also tried to pass dates as 'integers'  'dates': ['1406703000', '1406702700', ] but none of these are producing the right time of timestamps. What exactly is the format of timestamp expected when showing time-series data using highchart?

Comment: Your answer can be found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datas should be multiplied by 1000, and order ascending. Obviously you can get your json by javascitrp and parse all dates.

Comment: I have data in following format but it still shows me time stamp in 1970? Seconds - 1406851200 Date: 2014-07-31 17:00:00
Seconds - 1406851500 Date: 2014-07-31 17:05:00
{
    "chart_data": {
        "dates": [
            1406851200000, 
            1406851500000, 
        ], 
        "values": [
            {
                "data": [
                    54, 
                    60
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "data": [
                    84, 
                    90
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

Comment: You need to multiple your timestamps by 1000 and dates will be correct